# Как спрятать страницу от незалогиненых пользователей а после входа сделать редирект на эту страницу?

Tags: wordpress

Как спрятать страницу от незалогиненых пользователей а после входа сделать редирект на эту страницу ? WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как спрятать страницу от незалогиненых пользователей а после входа
>   сделать редирект на эту страницу ?

Можно в header нужного [шаблона](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page) вставить [auth_redirect();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/) и затем выбирать этот шаблон для нужных страниц/записей.